# Magento - Sort Products by ID

Tags: sorting, magento, product

I am trying to set up my Magento store to sort the products in the order that they were added to the catalog (by product ID). However, I haven't been able to find a good example of how to set this up. It seems to do this by default in most of my product categories, but not all of them.

I thought the sort by "Position" option on the frontend would do this, but it doesn't seem to work for all of my categories. I am using community edition 1.6.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Copy  :
  `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php`

to (create the appropiate folder ):
  `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php`

Find the following line in List.php :

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
```

add the following line below :

```
$this->_productCollection->joinField('category_product', 'catalog/category_product', 'product_id', 'product_id=entity_id', array('store_id'=> Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()), 'left');

// Here is the explain
/*
* @param string $alias 'category_product'
* @param string $table 'catalog/category_product'
* @param string $field 'name'
* @param string $bind 'PK(product_id)=FK(entity_id)'
* @param string|array $cond
* @param string $joinType 'left'
*
* default definition
* joinField($alias, $table, $field, $bind, $cond=null, $joinType='inner') 
*
*/
```

Copy
  `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php`

to
  `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php`

Find the following line in Config.php :

```
'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position')
```

Replace with :

```
$options = array(
   'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
   'product_id' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product ID')
);
```

PS : I am writing this article from home which I haven't got Magento installation on my machine, so I didn't test but the structure is OK. If you face of any toruble, make sure field and table name.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately your code doesn't appear to have any affect on the product order. It still isn't sorting by id in some categories. If it helps, it usually only happens when more than 9 or 10 products are in the category. Thanks again!

Comment: @BWDesign you mean, only sorting if it's available more than 10 products in a category, right?

Comment: Yes. If there are more that 9 or 10 products that display in a category, the sorting is incorrect. Also I notice that changing the sort direction does affect the items if it is sorted by "Position". I would think that it would sort by ID DESC then change to ID ASC, but apparently not.

Comment: @BWDesign if you don't mind, could you please echo or print out the $this variable? I curious about what returning value.

Comment: Do you mean echo it out in the List.php file? I'm not sure where to add the echo since the whole script is a function.

Comment: @BWDesign no, I wanted to look out product collection what was returning!

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite understand what you are asking. Can you give me more specific instructions on how to do this? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs:
Change this:

```
'product_id' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product ID')
```

to this:

```
'entity_id' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product ID')
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php
```

Find the following line in `Config.php` :

```
$options = array(
    'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position')
);
```

Replace with :

```
    $options = array(
//        'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position')
        'entity_id' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Last')
    );
```

then change the default sorting direction to descending:
open `app/design/frontend/your theme/your layout/layout/catalog.xml`
add the line

```
<action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
```

in block

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
   <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
      <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
here

   </block>
</block>
```